# Remove first instance of substring if its infront of string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have 2 types of strings:

**String 1**

```
<br/>Ask Me A Question<br />

                  |<br/>Search My Apartments<br/>
```

**String 2**

```
Ask Me A Question<br />

                  |<br/>Search My Apartments<br/>
```

How do I have a function that remove the first `<br/>` from the String 1 to get String 2, while not touching anything in String 2 if String 2 is passed into the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid using a regular expression you can check if `<br/>` occurs at the start of the string with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). If so, simply lop off the first five characters using [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
if (strpos($string, '<br/>') === 0) {
  $string = substr($string, 5);
}
```

Comment: Ha! Good answer. Sometimes you don't need regex!

Comment: Make sure you use the triple-equals (`===`) in case your version of php's `strpos` returns `false` (which will match 0 but won't `=== 0`)

Comment: @Tim Yes, it's probably worth pointing that out. IF you're asking such a question you probably aren't fully aware of the difference between double equals and triple equals.

Answer (score 1):

start your regex with `^` to match the beginning of the string.

```
preg_replace('/^<br\s?\/>/', '', $string)
```

EDIT: whoops, had an extra space (\s) in there!

EDIT 2: added an *optional* space back in!

Comment: Thanks for the props ... though I'm with you: When you're dealing with HTML you never know how it's going to look so you're often better off with a regex that allows for all the possibilities. Of course, DOM parsing is also your friend in such matters :)

Comment: Your regex does not work for the example given in the question

Comment: It's worth noting that the space character should be optional `\s?`

Comment: Notice the "\s" there is no space in the example so it doesn't match. @mathletics fixed it and it works now

Comment: @JoshStrange rdlowrey is right, considering that it's mixed in this example (I realize the first has no space but if dealing with input from, say, a CMS, who knows how it's actually going to shake out.)

Comment: @Mathletics Oh I agree, I was just pointing out that there was a problem, I think the optional space is the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `` `^<br/> `` with the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

@mathletics Answer is not correct for the example given in the question, This one works:

```
preg_replace('#^(<br/>)#iu', '', $string);
```

Comment: fixed mine; had an extra space character because I looked at the second break.